# how to install Talib for node in windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

Im trying to get one script to work and it need Talib. But im not able to get it to work under windows 10.

Its allso telling me `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/.NETFramework'`

I have found that you have to change the link to just framework, but i cant even find the file as there is no talib folder.

Answer (score 2):

I did managed to have Talib installed by installing the windows build tools for VS 2015

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

then setting the VS version for node to 2015:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015
```

after that Talib would install

```
npm install --save talib
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/talib for more details.